# how to get scanned barcode from socket mobile scanner which are scan without connecting android app?

Tags: android, bluetooth, socketmobile

When device is not connected with Android device. at that time I scan number of bar-code. now when device connect with Android device via bluetooth and "onDeviceArrival" method getting called. How to get previous scanned bar-code list. Is it Possible ?